# Why is the following group action free?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-actions, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M, \Omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and $G$ be a compact Lie group acting on $M$, such that the 2-form $\Omega$ is $G$-equivariant.  Let $m \in M$.  Let $V_m := {T_m(G.m)}^\Omega/({T_m(G.m)}^\Omega \cap T_m (G.m) )$, where $G.m$ denotes the orbit of M through the point $m$ and ${T_m(G.m)}^\Omega$ is a subspace of $T_m M$ which is orthogonal to $T_m(G.m)$ with respect to the symplectic form $\Omega$.

The vector space $V_m$ is symplectic with the symplectic form $\Omega_{V_m}$ defined by
$$\Omega_{V_m}([v],[w]):= \Omega_m(v,w)$$

For any $v, w \in T_m(G.m)$.

Let $H:= G_m$ be the isotropy group of $m$. The mapping $(h, [v]) \rightarrow [h.v]$, with $h \in H$ and $ [v] \in V_m$, defines an action of the Lie group $H$ on $V_m$, where $h.v$ denotes the tangent lift of the $G$-action on $TM$.

Why is the action $H$ on $V_m$ as described above is  free ?

Comment: What is your definition of a free action?

Comment: The only definition I know is that $G$ acts freely on a manifold $M$ if for every $m \in M $, $g.m=m$ implies that $g =e$ where $e$ denotes the identity element of the group $G$.

Comment: OK, then the $H$-action cannot be free since, by the definition, it fixes $0\in V_m$.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan,  $ 0 \in V_m$ is a class of an element of $(T_m(G.m) \cap {T_m(G.m)}^ \Omega)$, why it is fixed by every element in $H$ ?

Comment: I found this statement in the first line of the proof of Proposition 3.2.1  in the book Symmetry, Reduction, and stability in Hamiltonian system by Juan Pablo Ortega Lahuerta.

Comment: This is a linear action of a group on a vector space, so zero vector is necessarily fixed (by the entire group). It's possible that the author means something else by a free action or maybe the author is making a silly mistake, I do not know.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan, yes, maybe be the authors have another definition for free action. But I'm interested to know  if $v \in V_m$ different from zero and $h.v = v$ do this imply that $h =e$ ?

Comment: Ok, so you are modifying the definition of a free action (that's why I asked you about your definition of a free action!). The claim is still false, at least in some examples. For instance, consider $M=S^2\times S^2$ and $G=SO(3)$ acting by the standard action on the first factor and acting trivially on the 2nd factor. Take any point $m\in M$. I leave you to work out the details.

Comment: ok @Moishe Kohan,  thanks a lot for your comments.